# Portable Jetty server release

Tags: java, jetty, release

I would like to have a portable Jetty Server. The default jetty.home directory contains

```
    JettyHome
    │
    ├─etc
    │ ├─ jetty.xml
    │ ├─ jetty-logging.xml
    │ ├─ jetty-plus.xml
    │ └─ webdefault.xml
    ├─logs
    │
    ├─lib
    │  ├─ jetty-6.1.26.jar
    │  └─ other.jar
    ├─webapps
    │  └─MyWebApp.war 
    ├─ start.jar
    └─ start.ini
```

From the above, I would like to eliminate `etc` and `lib` directory and keep the following

```
    JettyHome
    │
    ├─logs
    ├─webapps
    │  └─MyWebApp.war 
    └─ start.jar
```

I packed all the `lib` folder jars into start.jar using [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net) along with `start.ini`. Is there any way to keep `etc` folder contents inside the jar so that I can simply run

```
java -Xmx640M -jar rw.jar
```

instead of

```
java -Xmx640M -jar rw.jar etc/jetty.xml etc/jetty-annotations.xml etc/jetty-deploy.xml etc/jetty-logging.xml etc/jetty-webapps.xml
```

So I can have a portable release and I never worry about changing configuration by someone in client place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to embed jetty into your application.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

With this you simply need to have the jetty jars in the classpath and you should be good to go.  You can even slurp everything into the one jar like you want and have a Main class in the manifest that starts everything off.

The xml files are really just a thin layer of xml over java anyway.  Take a look at some of the embedded examples here and that should clue you into the correct approach.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will do it.